# search: a random (x,y) closest point on a pre-defined 2D grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

We have predefined two vectors X-grid and Y-grid (same size), which has layout a 2D grid

for example:

```
X-grid = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.4,1.4,1.4,...,Xlast}, 
Y-grid = {10.0, 10.1,10.2,10.3,...,10.0, 10.1,10.2,10.3,...,Ylast}
```

One X grid can have multiple Y grid values, like x =1.0, y = 10.0,10.1,10.2,10.3,... vice versa, you can also think one y has multiple x, y = 10.0, x = 1.0,1.2,1.4,...

and user has randomly generated a point within X,Y-grid range, like x= 6.22233434, y = 12.356464

I want to search which grid point closest to user generated random point,
for this case, it will be x = 6.2, y = 12.3

the current solution I am using is pretty brutal, I am calculating the difference between user point and EACH grid point, and find the smallest difference to get the grid

but I truly think there shall be a smarter way to search for the closest point

Can any expert provide some suggestions or ideas?

NOTE: the step size for X and Y are changing for different cases

NOTE NOTE: for the above example, X step size is 0.2, Y is 0.3, but for other cases, it could be 0.1, 0.5, etc. Step size is preset in another step, it varies from case to case

Comment: The points of the grid can be defined as `(1+a*0,2,  10+b*0.1)`. You just need to find `a` and `b`, natural numbers.

Comment: For the example,  `X = 6.2`, `Y = 12.3`, suppose `x1` is the largest `x` for which `x <= X` and `x2` is the smallest `x` for which `x >= 2` and `y1` and `y2` are obtained similarly (`y1 <= Y <= y2`). Then clearly one need only find which of four points is closest to `X,Y`: `x1,y1`, `x1,y2`, `x2,y1`, `x2,y2`. Of course, we may have `x <= X` or `x >= X` for all `x`, or similar for `y`, in which case there may be only two or three points to compare. Of course, I may have misunderstood the question and it's not as simple as it seems. Aside: it seems irrelevant that the point is obtained randomly.

Comment: Step size being unknown isn't such a big deal, you could easily find it, maybe you can even get the step size directly from the "other step"? Once you have the step size, finding closest grid point is a special kind of rounding.